# Информация в GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play

Хочу обратиться к опытным Android-разработчикам. Какие именно установки показывают цифры над графиком на странице приложения? (строка типа "Установок:  X - Y"), эти числа не могут уменьшиться судя по всему. Просто на данный момент и количество активных, и общее количество установок перевалило за 100, а промежуток до сих пор 10-50. То что показывается количество установок за один последний день даже представить трудно, поэтому сразу исключил такой вариант.

На графике как я понял показываются активные установки.
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно в play.google.com показывает график установок за день. по X - дни, по Y - количество установок.

Comment: я про другое, цифры установок над графиком (например у злых птиц 50000000-100000000, что нереально за один день)

про график то я знаю

Comment: А это всего установок

Comment: Эта информация, просто, достаточно странно обновляется. В консоли быстрее.

Comment: Понятно, просто уже 3й день не обновляется)

Comment: _upd_ на 3й день обновились наконец-то цифры. Радует :)

Comment: @rasmisha Делитесь ссылкой, будем тестить.